# Formato de codificação do value (input)

Tags: javascript, codificação-de-caracteres, iso-8859-1

Problema:
Estou passando o valor de um input para um frame porém o formato de codificação não fica como deveria - charset=ISO-8859-1

Tentando isso:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function update() {
 var html = document.getElementById('edit').value;
 var encodedHtml = unescape(encodeURIComponent(html));
 document.getElementById('carregar').src = 'data:text/javascript;charset=utf-8,' + encodedHtml;
 }
 window.onload = update;
 </script>
 <input type="hidden" id='edit' onkeyup='update();' onchange='update();' onload='update();' value='a&#231;&#227;o e reação'>
 <iframe id='carregar' style='width:100%;border:1px solid gray;height:50%;'></iframe>
```

Comment: porque não usa UTF-8 em vez de ISO-8859-1 ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugestão de correção:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript">
function update() {
    var html = encodeURI(document.getElementById('edit').value);
    document.getElementById('carregar').src = 'data:text/javascript;charset=utf-8,' + html;
}
window.onload = update;
</script>
<input type="hidden" id='edit' onkeyup='update();' onchange='update();' onload='update();' value='ação e reação'>
<iframe id='carregar' style='width:100%;border:1px solid gray;height:50%;'></iframe>
```

**Importante**: Certifique-se de que o editor de texto esteja como `ANSI` compatível com `ISO-8859-1`.

Comment: Muito bom é o que precisava.